# Create a business rule in MDM 2012 that tests the Sum of attributes of an entity

Tags: business-intelligence, business-rules, master-data-services, master-data-management

I have created an entity on **MDM 2012** and I like to create a business rule that tests if the SUM of 3 attributes is 100.

I didn't find a way on the Action Panel to use arithmetic operators or simply a SUM function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure we can perform this directly or not but yes we can use custom user defined script to validate Sum of attribute values=100 or anything

try follow these steps -

Step#1
Creating a business rule with custom extensions in MDS; for that create a user define function in SQL to validate sum of 3 or 4 parameter is 100 or not

e.g.
[image]

make sure function created under USR schema and RETURNS BIT

Step #2

Create Business Rule & select function created in step#1 as Operator

[image]

Make sure to click somewhere inside the parameter box. This will change the layout and allow you to assign an attribute to the parameter of the user defined script.

Step #3
What to do if condition met or not met

like 
[image]

[Reference Business Rules Extension in MDS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4671/business-rules-extension-in-master-data-services-2016/)

Comment: Thank you for your response but we can't find, *User defined Script* on the Business Rules View.